# Match against query in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT MATCH(Firstname,Lastname)
AGAINST('+hy'IN BOOLEAN MODE)Firstname,Lastname 
FROM tbldemo
```

This is my query, but the table is returning the entire table instead of returning the data contains 'hy'.  How can it be possible?

Comment: Could you edit some more info in - which database are you using?  Are you really a member of the KKK? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need a where clause...

How about this:

```
SELECT Firstname,Lastname 
FROM tbldemo 
WHERE MATCH(Firstname,Lastname) AGAINST('+hy' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```